# Using Timer with For Loop to Halt Execution

Tags: c#, .net, timer

```
for(int i=0; i<mylist.items.count; i++)
{
   if(i==myvalue[i])
   {
     //call Timer! Wait timer interval if timer is tick, continue for loop!
   }

   timer_click()
   {
   // application
   }
}
```

How can I use the `for` loop with timer to pause execution if the value in the conditional is a certain value?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't. Why do you want to, or what are you trying to do by this?

Use Thread.Sleep() if you want the loop to stop for a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use Thread.Sleep() no? But you really should have a good reason to put a timer on the server side, [it's not considered a good thing](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if I understand the question but you should read about the stopwatch class

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want to pause execution of something? This would certainly make for a poor user experience. Think before you use it.... But like others have said ... its

```
Thread.Sleep(some ms);
```